# Can psychological services be deducted on Canadian income taxes?

Tags: income-tax, canada, tax-deduction

When filing my yearly income taxes, is there a place where psychological services such as weekly therapy with a psychologist can be deducted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/deductions-credits-expenses/lines-33099-33199-eligible-medical-expenses-you-claim-on-your-tax-return/authorized-medical-practitioners-purposes-medical-expense-tax-credit.html) you can claim it if you don't live in the Yukon.  You claim it on [line 33099](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/life-events/what-when-someone-died/final-return/complete-final-return-steps/common-types-income-a-final-return/federal-non-refundable-tax-credits/line-33099-medical-expenses-self-spouse-partner-children-under-18.html).

You tax software should do the calculations for you if you enter it as a medical expense.

Comment: According to [this page](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/deductions-credits-expenses/lines-33099-33199-eligible-medical-expenses-you-claim-on-your-tax-return/details-medical-expenses.html) you must be eligible for the disability tax credit in order to deduct therapy as a medical expense, and the DTC is quite strict, so it seems like an average person receiving standard 'talk' therapy from a psychologist is not accepted.  Am I reading this right?

Comment: If the psychologist is a psychotherapist it's allowed in ON and QC.   They have to be registered/licensed as such in the province.  If you're seeing a psychologist you may be able to qualify for the DTC.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exactly what the role and qualifications of the person giving you the psychological services is. This is [a list of the different medical practitioners whose work is allowable as medical expenses in different provinces](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/deductions-credits-expenses/lines-33099-33199-eligible-medical-expenses-you-claim-on-your-tax-return/authorized-medical-practitioners-purposes-medical-expense-tax-credit.html).

The easiest way to find out is to ask your psychologist. They will have been asked this question many times.